# How to set up customize short cuts in grease pencil?

Tags: shortcut

I need to create short cuts for brush, eraser, and fill tools, also need to create customize shortcuts.

Can I record process and save shortcuts for that?

Comment: Right-click on the tool's icon and choose "Assign shortcut"?